# Unable to install devstack in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, failed-installation, devstack

I followed the steps below, but I'm getting an error.

1. Install Virtual Box (version 5.0.0) running on Windows 7 host machine.
2. Install Ubuntu server version 14.04.02 on it.
3. git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
4. cd devstack; cp samples/local.conf .
5. After that i ran ./stack.sh but came with this error after running for approx 30 minutes:

> 2015-07-21 20:04:18.841 | ERROR (ConnectionRefused): Unable to establish connection to 10.0.2.15:8774/v2/c199aa06389a4c8c85dffddad18fce1b/flavors/… 2015-07-21 20:04:20.433 | + exit 1 deb@Devstack:~/devstack$

Please help me in resolving the issue

Answer (score 2):

Try re-running the stack. Thats the best hack i found for DevStack debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some specific network settings in virtual box to overcome this error.

1. From the Network section, change Attached to to Bridged Adapter, Adapter Type to Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net) and Promiscuous Mode to Allow All.
2. Check Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-v from System > Processor .
3. Select USB Tablet as the Pointing Device from System > Motherboard.
4. Then restart the virtual machine and check ifconfig for a new IP, add it in local.conf and then try install script again.

It should work this time :-)